# Running a custom module in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file called `index.js`, which is my main file. I also made a file called `router.js` for the routing. I am trying to import the `router.js` module into the `index.js` file and run it as soon as the `index.js` is run.

This is the code inside of `router.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/users',function(req,res,next){
    res.json([
        {id: 1, name: 'Jorge'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Emanuella'}      
    ])
})
```

And this is my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const router = require('./router')

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

When I do `console.log(router)`, I get an empty object.

I want the router to run when the `index.js` starts working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to *export* `app` from router.js:

```
 module.exports = app;
```

Also, `app` should really be an Express router:

```
const app = express.Router();
```

Comment: i would also change the name of the export from app to router. just a personal thing but i find it helps

Comment: I am getting an error saying `Cannot GET /users`

Comment: You have to mount the router.